# Вопрос насчет input() в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста: как сделать, чтобы при пропуске ввода числа в  `input()` не выдавало ошибки, а просто заново запрашивался ввод.

Comment: Перехватывайте ошибку через try-except

Comment: Цикл нужно использовать, пока не получишь то, что нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def smart_int_input():
    try:
        return int(input("number = "))
    except:
        print("Must be number!!!")
        return smart_int_input()
# __main__
smart_int_input()
```

Если без функций:

```
while True:
    try:
        test = int(input("number = "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Must be number!!!")

print(test)
```